# Cursor resets to default after adding pointer-events:none in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, mouse-cursor

I've encountered a strange behaviour regarding CSS relationship between CSS `pointer-events` and `cursor` rules in Firefox. When I set an element's `cursor` to any value different from `auto` (let's say it's `wait`), the type of the cursor changes accordingly, as expected. However, when I also add `pointer-events: none` to the same element, the cursor is reset to `auto`. The same happens if I use `cursor: wait !important`. The very same rules work correctly in Chromium and IE (!).

In the beginning I thought that this may be expected behaviour when `pointer-events: none` is set, but according to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) section about the `none` value:

> The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.

It appears that the *Javascript* events, not *CSS* events won't be propagated.

The question is: is there a way to use both `pointer-events: none` and `cursor: wait` on the same element in Firefox? Also, am I right about the interpretation of Javascript/CSS events regarding the mentioned excerpt?

If it matters, I'm using Firefox 31 on Ubuntu 64bit

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dolorem/z41fb3ex/2/). In this case I'm adding rules dynamically, but the same occurs when using CSS only. The scenario I'm talking about is `Change cursor to wait --> Disable pointer events`

Comment: same behavior on Firefox 31, Windows

Comment: Almost a year later, I am seeing the same behavior on Firefox 38 *and* Chrome 43 *and* IE11! My Linux box is at home so I can't confirm Chromium.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out that you have to set cursor on the parent element.

Setting both styles on one element or cursor on nested element resets the cursor to default pointer.

```
<div class="cursor-wait">
    <a href="#">wait</a>
    <div class="no-pointer-events">
        <a href="#">wait > no events</a><!-- works here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/piotr_cz/943pe0mm/1/) for details.

Comment: Looks like Bootstrap needs to update its framework, because it doesn't do this with disabled buttons and maybe others. To be honest, it seems hard with the buttons because Bootstrap only knows you have a button you want disabled, which may or may not have children, and there isn't an easy (cross-browser) way to get the parent in CSS.